# assertion failed on expression go isactive () && go gettag () != 0 unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This error is harmless to my game development but it hurts my eye by seeing it from time to time . How can i get rid of this error on unity .

> Assertion failed: Assertion failed on expression: 'go.IsActive() && go.GetTag() != 0'UnityEngine.Camera:get_main()

It came out when i find an object using tag

```
public GameObject shadowUnderWater;

void OnEnable(){
  //uSkyManager Instantiates
    if(shadowUnderWater == null){
        shadowUnderWater = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SkyManager");
    }
}
```

What i did so far is this :

```
void Awake(){
  Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera> ();
}
```

I set the camera on the `Awake` function because i saw in some forum the you just need to instantiate the camera.

Comment: What's the Unity version?

Comment: 2017.2.0f3 sir @Programmer

Comment: You don't have to call me sir. Are you using any plugin?

Comment: No plugins yet . It came out when i tried using `FindObjectWithTag` on my `UnderWater.cs` Script

Comment: Are you sure that `FindObjectWithTag` is the ussye? Comment it out and see if the problem is still there then uncomment it out and see what happens too.

Comment: ow its not . Haha its funny because it came out really when i added that code. Should i post my whole code @Programmer?

Comment: No. Don't post your whole code. Not sure if that will be helpful. I suggest you comment everything in all your scripts and see if the problem is still there. After that, start uncommenting the scripts one by one and see if you can find which one is causing that issue.

Comment: Thank you very much . I will :) may god bless you sir.

Comment: I comment out everything still the error exist. @Programmer

Comment: Ok. I have ran into similar problem in the past and it was a bug. Close Unity backup your project and make a duplicate of it. In the new duplicate, delete the "Library"  and the "ProjectSettings" folder from your project then open the project. Wait for Unity to re-import everything then test and see if the error is still there

Comment: Did that last night and it didn't actually helped me. :)

Comment: You deleted both the "Library" and the "ProjectSettings" folder?

Comment: Yup. I did that . But still it occurs.

Comment: This is a bug. Create new project and see if that happens. If it's gone, copy your files one by one to the new project. I know it sucks but the only way I was able to fix this was after updating. It looks like you are already using newest version of Unity so creating new project is what I recommend now.

Comment: It doesn't hurt actually my project but it's just irritating because it is red. I'll try that one sir .

Answer (score 1):

1. there's no need to get the component of the camera
2. if the camera is null then obviously getting a component from it will fail
3. what you do in Awake is meaningless, there's no concept of *preparing/getting* a camera

See the documentation on how to use this member:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html

This is how you should do work involving your camera:

```
var cam = Camera.main;
if (cam != null)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Note: `Camera.main` is an uncached redirect to `GameObject.Find()` which is slow, avoid using it in places like `Update()`.

Comment: But still the error still exist. that's what i wanted here