# FindGameObjectWithTag in an Array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a lil bit of trouble because it says on my error

> 'Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.GameObject ' to ' UnityEngine.GameObject[] '

Here's what my script looks like;

```
 public GameObject[] rotateLilies;
 void Start(){
     rotateLilies = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("WaterLilies");
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
     foreach(GameObject waterLilies in rotateLilies){
         waterLilies.transform.Rotate(0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
     }
 }
```

What i want here is obviously put all the that has a `WaterLilies` tag and put it on my Arrays of GameObject then apply my rotate script to all of them. But it always have that error above.

Help.

Comment: Closed as a typo issue. It is `FindGameObjectsWithTag`. Notice the `s` in Object.

Comment: i tried `FindGameObjectsWithTag` but still the error occur sir @Programmer

Comment: That should solve the error you mentioned in this question. If you have unrelated error, create a new question.

Comment: Put an answer sir @Programmer then i'll mark it as correct

Comment: Actually could you help me with this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848361/assertion-failed-on-expression-go-isactive-go-gettag-0-unity) sir

Comment: This question is not worth answering since it's just a typo. I will take a look at your other question.